# Retrieve data from the nested list

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists

How can I get all data from a nested list in C#?

Each person can have multiple cars.

Now I have a list of people and each item has a list of cars.

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And values:

```cs
var people = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person()
    {
        FullName = "Jack Lee",
        Cars = new List<Car>()
        {
            new Car()
            {
                Name = "BMW"
            },
            new Car()
            {
                Name = "Tesla"
            }
        }
    },
    new Person
    {
        FullName = "Micheal doug",
        Cars = new List<Car>()
        {
            new Car()
            {
                Name = "Ferrari"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

What is the best way to get all car names with one query?

Is it possible to get all cars with one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With *System.Linq*, you can use `.SelectMany()` to flatten the `Cars` lists from the `people` list and get the `Name`.

```cs
using System.Linq;

var result = people.SelectMany(x => x.Cars)
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .ToList();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eGCZOp)